# How do we extend, stabilize, and give a finished look to an outside faucet that is attached to the house?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, outdoor

We have three issues we want to resolve regarding an outside faucet.

1. We want to extend the faucet about 4" from the siding,
2. We want to stabilize the faucet because it is bouncing around in the pipe hole,
3. We want to give it a finished look when done, because it is on the front of the house.

What product/products should we use to accomplish all three, and how should we install those products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 4" block of pressure-treated wood, or cedar.

A drill.

A frost-free-sillcock 4" longer than the connection to the pipe inside to the outside wall surface.

Some screws, type dependent on wall materials.

Paint. Optional on cedar for certain values of "finished look"

Comment: It will be attached to Hardie siding so should we caulk around the wood block ~ we are new at this.